# Euler's laws - derivation

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics

It looks simple and maybe is easy, but I don't get it. How to obtain the second equality from the first one below?

Source: http://emweb.unl.edu/NEGAHBAN/EM373/note19/note19.htm

[image]

They took derivative of both sides of the first equation (after multiplying both sides by $m$). The left side is obvious. But we have an integral on the right side - shouldn't [Leibniz integral rule](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule) be used there? Is $r$ a function of mass and time, or only mass? It was a rhetorical question - obviously it doesn't depend on mass or time. But then, why take a time derivative of $r$ if it doesn't change with time?

---

**EDIT**

Right, $r$ does change with time.

Why $\frac{d}{dt}\int_m r dm = \int_m \frac{d}{dt} r dm$? I guess $r$ is not a function of $m$ (mass), therefore it is a constant.

Could anyone show the steps to transform the left side to the right side of this equality?: $\frac{d}{dt}\int_m r dm = \int_m \frac{d}{dt} r dm$

You don't simply take derivative of elements inside the integral (at least in general, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule)). So why can we do it in this case?

Comment: well, look at the picture: *does* $\boldsymbol r$ *change in time?*

Comment: @AccidentalFourierTransform of course it doesn't change in time, and it's not a function of mass neither. Then why take a time derivative of it? We know it's a constant.

Comment: @user5539357 - no, $r$ _does_ change with time; that's why it has a derivative called "velocity"...

Comment: r is the spatial location of a specific parcel of mass at time t.  If we take the derivative of r with respect to t, following the parcel of mass, we get its velocity.

Comment: @ChesterMiller okay, $r$ is a function of time, but is it a function of mass as well? I think nothing can be a function of $m$, because you can generally have two particles of identical mass, at different locations (and it would mean assigning two values to the same $m$).

Comment: It's not a function of m, provided you are following the same parcel of mass dm throughout its travels.  If we label the tiny masses as ($dm_1,...,dm_j,.....dm_n$), then r is a function of t and the parcel number j.  I hope that makes sense.  And the local velocity is the time derivative or r holding j constant.  So, $v_j=\frac{\partial r(t,j)}{\partial t}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mass is not a function of time, so the only thing inside the integral that needs differentiating is the position.

Let me try to make this clearer. The integral over $m$ is really the integral over the volume:

$$\int_m r \cdot dm = \int_V r \cdot\rho(r')~ dV$$

Here I deliberately distinguish between $r$, the vector from the origin of the coordinate system, and $r'$, a dummy variable that describes a point in the volume of the body, and which is not changing (because it is defined in the coordinate system of the body, and only used to help with the integration). The integral is taken over all the volume elements that comprise the body. For a chosen orientation of the body, there is a particular relationship - that is, for every point $r'$ there is a corresponding $r$. But I can choose my integration such that $r'$ does not change with time (it is a "snapshot in time" of the first moment of mass of the body - if the body moves, its coordinate system moves with it, so the same point continues to have the same $r'$).

Now you can see that the only term in this equation that is time dependent is $r$, and that's why the integral is performed the way it is.

Comment: Because $\frac{dm}{dt}=0$

Comment: Because $r$ is not a function of $m$ (right?), $\frac{d}{dt}\int_m r dm = \frac{d}{dt}(r \int_m dm)$. Then $\frac{d}{dt}(r \int_m dm)=\frac{d}{dt}r \int_m dm$ (because $\int_m dm$ is a constant). $\frac{d}{dt}r$ is a constant as well, so we can conclude that $\frac{d}{dt}\int_m r dm=\int_m \frac{d}{dt} r dm$. Is that correct?

Comment: No - while you are integrating over the "mass", you are in fact taking the first moment of mass (by multiplying by the distance $r$) so you can't just drag it out of the integral. $r$ is a function of whichever element of mass you are currently looking at.

Comment: Then how to write it out step by step? If $r$ is a function of $m$ and $t$,  should I use Leibniz integral rule? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_integral_rule

Comment: @user5539357 - I've tried to give more details. See if it's clear now.

Comment: I still can't see how to show that $\frac{d}{dt}\int_m r dm = \int_m \frac{d}{dt} r dm$, or at least write it mathematically.

Comment: Take the derivative of each component inside the integral in turn; you will find that there is only one nonzero term (namely the one with $\frac{dr}{dt}$ since the other terms don't change with $t$, so their derivative is zero.